# jQuery is changing my HTML

Tags: jquery

I’m trying to insert a HTML string after a specific element. But jQuery change the HTML code.

This is my code:

```
$(".poDetails")
    .find("tr")
    .eq(14).after('</table><div style="page-break-after: always;"></div><table>');
```

But jQuery inserts:

```
<div style="page-break-after: always;"></div><table></table>
```

Any idea how to prevent this? O what is wrong?

Thanks!

Edgar.

Update----

this is the complete code:

```
    <table class="poDetails">
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>

    n times...

</table>
```

this is what I trying to do:

```
<table class="poDetails">
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>

    //this is what i'm inserting. after tr number 14 (just assume that this is the 14 tr)
</table>
    <div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
<table>

    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr> 

</table>
```

Comment: Use valid HTML in the first place, and you won't have this problem.

Comment: it's because `</table>` is not treated as valid. it's a closing tag. jQuery then parses `<div>` which is properly opened and closed as well as `<table>`, assumed to be a self-closing tag.

Comment: @Brad - which can be shortened to: 'Your HTML is invalid.' let's try to be less negative!

Comment: @Brad - not to pick on you specifically. I'm guilty as well, and I've recently decided to call people out on it if I sense some negativity. I'm not perfect, and I expect the same treatment, but let's make programming a more welcoming subject!

Comment: Incorrect, please see my answer - the HTML is perfectly valid, as is the order.  The problem is that jQuery is interpreting the html and transforming it in to `createElement()` calls - the first closing table is ignored, and the last table is automatically closed for completeness.

Comment: Actually, the code is valid. I just assume that my intentions were clear in the jquery statement. look my Update.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you simply swapped the start and end tags of your table in the code. I haven't ever touched jQuery in my life to answer this, just to say that you should pay more attention to your own code correctness before blaming API's and libraries for doing stuff you don't expect ;)

Comment: The code is valid. If you haven't ever touched jQuery in your life, why you are answering a JQUERY question?

Comment: Because that code snippet just explained itself. Furthermore, if the author would have given the rest of his HTML from the beginning, I would have known what he was up to.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're experiencing is that using the `$('...')` format with html elements actually **creates** the elements.  So, with the code you have, it's trying to create all those elements you specify - it is **not** the same as trying to inject raw html in to the document!

What you want is to do `.html('</table><div style="page-break-after: always;"></div><table>')` to have jQuery insert the html you've specified as is and not interpret it in any way.

Comment: That make sense… the only problem is that I need to insert the code AFTER the TR, but if I use .html(), it will replace the content of the TR.

Comment: Select the containing element with the HTML you need to append to, then do something like `$(this).html($(this).html() + '...extra html...')`.  Pretty hacky, but a learning start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) or [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) to actually move DOM elements around the page:

```
$(".poDetails tr:gt(13)").wrap("<table/>").insertAfter( $(".poDetails"));
$(".poDetails").after("<div style='page-break-after: always;'></div>");
```

This will select the tr elements in `.poDetails` that have an index greater than 13, wrap them in a table, and move them to be after `table.poDetails`.

Then it inserts your page break div between the two tables.

When you pass in a jQuery object(s) that have been selected, the `.after` method will move them instead of cloning or creating it. (Also true for `.insertAfter`, `.before`, and `.insertBefore`.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is modified instruction

```
var your_data = 'what ever you want to put';
$(".poDetails tr").eq(14).after(your_data);
```